# Nginx Rewrite rules for clean URLs

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I want to write nginx rewrite rules for clean URLs.

Everytime the user hits;

```
http://domain.com/abc/12/16/abc-def-ghi
```

I need to execute

```
domain.com/abc.php?a=12&b=16&c=abc-def-ghi
```

Now my regex is right as per rubular:

```
^\/abc\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\w+\S+)$
```

http://rubular.com/regexes/11063

and rule is

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
  rewrite ^\/abc\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\w+\S+)$ abc.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 last;
}
```

But it is giving "No input File specified". I cant find what the problem is?

Comment: Do it the easy way!
Get a .htaccess example, and convert it here: http://www.anilcetin.com/

Answer (score 1):

"No input File specified" error is coming form php-handler.
This means rewrite rule is working fine but some other line is not prefixing proper base_dir.

**Try this...**

Replace

`rewrite ^\/abc\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\w+\S+)$ abc.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 last;`

With

`rewrite ^\/abc\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\w+\S+)$ /abc.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 last;`

Please note `/ (slash)` before `abc.php` in above line.

**Also problem can be...**

1. In `location ~ \.php$ {}` block. I hope u have one for sure in your full config :-)
2. There must be a line like - `root   /var/www/exmaple.com;` in your config. If its in `location \ {..}` block, you may need to copy it to the `location ~ \.php$ {}` or move outside `location \ {..}` but inside `server {..}` block.

If you can paste your nginx config here, it will be easier to debug. :-)